# Hosting static website with Django

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-admin

I have Django app running live on AWS at, `www.domain.com/admin`. It doesn't posses any html pages, we only make use of Django-Admin.

Now I have to host a website at `www.domain.com`.
I have my website package in this form,

```
site
 |-sass
 |-js
 |-img
 |-fonts
 |-css
 |-index.html
```

I copy-pasted my `site` folder inside my Django app at `my_django_app/templates/`

Also, added this :

```
url(r'^$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='site/index.html')),
```

inside `my_django_app/my_django_app/urls.py`.

And, updated my `settings.py` with,

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates/site'),
]
```

Now when I runserver and go to `www.domain.com`, it loads my html file without CSS, JS and Images.

Please suggest me what I am doing wrong.

I am a beginner to python and also never hosted a website ever before.

Comment: I'd rather not use Django for static website. A webserver like Nginx would be faster than Django at this.

Comment: @xyres I understand this, but in my case I just have one instance, and I need to have website and its admin dashboard to be on same IP.

Comment: You can configure your webserver to forward traffic to Django if request is made at `www.domain.com/admin` while server other URLs directly.

Comment: @xyres Can you suggest me how that can be done, I am using Amazon Linux with Apache server.

Answer (score 1):

This answer is a reply to [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39317434/hosting-static-website-with-django?noredirect=1#comment65967301_39317434), not an answer to the original question.

1. In your Apache config, change: `WSGIScriptAlias /` to `WSGIScriptAlias /admin`.
2. Add this before the `</VirtualHost>` closing tag:

   ```
   Alias / /path/to/static/site/
   <Directory /path/to/static/site/>
       Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
       AllowOverride All
       Order Deny,Allow
       Allow from all
   </Directory>
   ```

I haven't tested it, but I believe this should work.